# How to apply uniform letter spacing to all the letters being added to the TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield, letter-spacing

Is it possible to apply letter spacing uniformly based on the text form field width and the letters being added to it?

For example, consider that my text form field width is 50, and I add a five-letter word to it. My expectation here is that I want each letter to be uniformly spaced (say 10 here) within the text field.

Can anyone share your input on this?

Comment: If you use a fixed-pitch font, like Courier, you should have uniform widths.  It'll just look ugly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Apply [`FontFeature.tabularFigures`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FontFeature/FontFeature.tabularFigures.html) to style provided to your [`TextField.style`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/style.html)

*reference*: [`TextStyle.fontFeatures`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/fontFeatures.html)

Comment: Thanks. But this approach leads us to use external Monospace fonts (Google fonts). Is there an alternative way to achieve the requirement without using the monospace fonts?

Comment: MY answer does not require any new fonts?